# Min Max Scheme coord.x0 y0 x1 y1

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, max, min

```
;; makeRectangle -- constructor for 'rectangle

(define makeRectangle
  (lambda (x0 y0 x1 y1)
       (makeGraph 'rectangle
               (list (makePoint x0 y0)
                     (makePoint x1 y1)))))
```

`(makeRectangle 3 2 1 7)` must return `(rectangle (point 1 7) (point 3 2))`
and I will get the same return for `(makeRectangle 1 2 3 7)` or `(makeRectangle 1 7 3 2)`, I have to use:

```
min x0 x1 min y0 y1 
max x0 x1 max y0 y1
```

But I don't know how to do. Could you please help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
(define makeRectangle
  (lambda (x0 y0 x1 y1)
    (makeGraph 'rectangle
               (makePoint (min x0 x1) (max y0 y1))
               (makePoint (max x0 x1) (min y0 y1)))))
```

such as

```
-> (makeRectangle 3 2 1 7)
'(rectangle (point 1 7) (point 3 2))

-> (makeRectangle 1 2 3 7) 
'(rectangle (point 1 7) (point 3 2))

-> (makeRectangle 1 7 3 2) 
'(rectangle (point 1 7) (point 3 2))

-> (makeRectangle 3 7 1 2)
'(rectangle (point 1 7) (point 3 2))
```